# CSS and JS Files in JQuery Mobile Site

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-mobile

Do we need to include CSS and JS files in every html page of mobile site developed in JQueryMobile?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

I think it's not in the [documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/index.html) or I just missed it.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a single html document with a `<div data-role="page">` for each page that you need in your application. Check out source code of [Multi page template](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/multipage-template.html).

```
<html>

   <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
     <title>Multi-page template</title> 

     <!-- CSS and JS files here-->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js">/script>
   </head> 


   <body> 

     <div data-role="page" id="first">
       <!-- Code for your first page -->
     </div>

     <div data-role="page" id="second">
       <!-- Code for your second page -->
     </div>

  </body>
</html>
```